# No registered instrumentation, errors when running unit tests

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I encountered a weird error in my test unit.

```
public class GameActivityUnitTest {
    private static ActivityScenario<GameActivity> scenario;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void createLogHistory() {
        scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(GameActivity.class);
        // WHEN
        scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
    }
    @Test
    public void testPointsChange() {
        scenario.onActivity(activity -> {
            activity.increaseCoin();
            activity.increaseCoin();
            activity.decreaseCoin();
            assertTrue(activity.coins == 1);;
        });
    }
    @Test
    public void testGamePauseStatus() {
        scenario.onActivity(activity -> {
            activity.view.getTimerController().pause();
            assertTrue(activity.view.getPauseStatus());
            activity.view.getTimerController().resume();
            assertTrue(activity.coins == 1);;
            assertFalse(activity.view.getPauseStatus());
        });
    }
}
```

I think function tagged as `@BeforeClass` is shared by all the following test units.

What I display gives my the "No instrumentation registered" error.

However, if I delete @BeforeClass method but repeat the code in each test units.

The error disappears.

Why this happens?

And I don't want the code to be repeated every time, what should I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some code before every test is run, you should use the `@Before` annotation (not `@BeforeClass`).

That means that you can easily launch the activity under test in your `createLogHistory()` (which should now not be static).